# Fingerprint is marked rejected

Tags: exit-relays, log

> [warn] http status 400 ("Fingerprint is marked rejected -- please contact us?") response from dirserver '171.25.193.9:443'. Please correct.

That's what I got in tor logs after starting new exit node on fresh VPS.
3 days passed but Atlas shows it offline.
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Contact bad-relays@lists.torproject.org

Answer (score 1):

The IP address 171.25.193.9 belongs to the host [maatuska.4711.se](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/171.25.193.9) which is a directory authority within the Tor network. It seems it has banned your relay from the network (*Fingerprint is marked rejected*). So maybe it was the case that your relay messed with traffic or people thought it was harmful to the network. People could [report bad relays](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/ReportingBadRelays). So please check your configuration and make sure that you relaying traffic without interfering it.

If this is the case then you should contact the [bad-relays mailing list](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/emailLists) 
and ask for removal.